# Count elements in a box

Tags: python, numpy

I have a part of a code that counts what is in the x,y and z columns of a data set for a given range. What I want it to do is count only those values that are in  x, y and z. Basically what I am trying to do is have the code count the number of values in a 3D box. How can I modify the following to do so? Thanks in advance

```
Sx = ((min <= X) & (X <= max)).sum()    #count what is in x range
Sy = ((min <= Y) & (Y <= max)).sum()    #count what is in y range
Sz = ((min <= Z) & (Z <= max)).sum()    #count what is in z range
```

Comment: Doy you want all these conditions to hold simultaneously?  Just `&` them together.

Comment: @Sven its that easy? Thank you!

Comment: While it will happen to work for booleans, you really mean a logical `and` here, not a bitwise `&`.

Comment: @kindall it actually counts what is in x, y, and z quite well

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: For NumPy arrays, you *must* use `&` instead of `and`.  The latter cannot be overloaded in Python.  See the (rejected) [PEP 335](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) for details.

Comment: oops, sorry! The `&` should have gotten me to pay more attention...

Comment: Ah, curses. Numpy is deep magic; I'd forgotten. Could they not get things like `min < X < max` to work, or did they decide deliberately not to do that for some reason?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: They can't; this would also require to overload `and`.  One of the motivations for PEP 335 was to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure if this really is what you want, but anyway:

```
count = ((min < X) & (X < max) & 
         (min < Y) & (Y < max) &
         (min < Z) & (Z < max)).sum()
```

Comment: Hi Sven, when I `&` them together it seems as if the `sum()` function is counting the number of time that there is a common value in x,y, and z. how do I get it to count the values? for example say I set the min to 1 and the max to 2, and then have `[0 0 0], [1 1 2], and [2 1 2]` sum will give me 2, but what I am looking for is 6. Is there a way to do that?  Also can you point me towards a good tutorial on stuff like this?

Comment: I've got no idea how this is supposed to result in `6` (the above code would give `0`, by the way).  Are you looking for the sum of `Sx`, `Sy` and `Sz` from your question?  If yes, just add them.

Comment: I apologize for my bad notation I was thinking in terms of a matrix where `[0 0 0]` was the first row. What I meant was if we had three arrays `X=[0 1 2], Y=[0 1 1], and Z=[0 2 2]` there would be six values in the range of greater than or equal 1 and and less than or equal to 2. It seems to me that what the sum function does is count the sets where X, Y and Z are in that range which in this case is 2.

Comment: @Surfcast23: I got the notation.  The result will be `0` because we use `<` all the time, and neither `1 < 1` nor `2 < 2` hold.  I didn't notice you edited the original post to use `<=` everywhere.  I've got still no idea why you expect `6`.

Comment: Hi Sven the reason I expect 6 is because in the range I stated       `1 <= X,Y,Z <= 2`  there are six values that hold. Unless I am not getting something.

Comment: @Surfcast23: Then how about `Sx` + `Sy` + `Sz`?

Comment: I want to make sure that what is counted is not only in the specified range, but common to all arrays. Say a value in the X array is in the range, but Y does not contain that value then I don't want it counted.

Comment: @Surfcast23: In that case, use the method in this answer and multiply by 3.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to `&` all three conditions together.

Alternatively, since `min` and `max` are the same for all three dimensions, you could use [`np.minimum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and [`np.maximum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) like so:

```
((min < np.minimum(X, Y, Z)) & (np.maximum(X, Y, Z) < max)).sum()
```

P.S. I recommend calling `min` and `max` something else so that they don't shadow [the](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) [builtins](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max).